# Correct formulation for Logistic regression using glmfit in Matlab

Tags: matlab, logistic-regression

When using glmfit in matlab, there are different problem setups that can be used:

```
      x = [2100 2300 2500 2700 2900 3100 ...
      3300 3500 3700 3900 4100 4300]'; 
      n = [48 42 31 34 31 21 23 23 21 16 17 21]';
      y = [1 2 0 3 8 8 14 17 19 15 17 21]';

      [b dev] = glmfit(x,[y n],'binomial','link','probit');
```

Here they fit numerical data where n is the number of items tested, and y is the number of successes.

```
      X = meas(51:end,:);
      y = strcmp('versicolor',species(51:end));

      b = glmfit(X,y,'binomial','link','logit')
```

In this case the y variable is binary and no n value is required (is that correct?)

In my case I have data on greyhoud races.

For each race I have a dummy variable (y) that takes value one when the dog wins and zero otherwise.

Q1.) For this setup I should use this formulation correct (with no n value supplied)?

[b dev] = glmfit(X,y,'binomial','link','logit')

Q2.) What is the precise definition of dev? It says in the support that it is a generalization of the residual sum of squares squares, but does not define it precisely.

Thanks